# LINQ for XML return "default node" when query node not found

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have this piece of code:

```
string name = "1";
string company = "abc";

XElement config = XElement.Parse (
@"<config>
    <applLists>
        <applList name='1'>
            <default>
                <applName>appl1-default-1</applName>
                <applName>appl2-default-1</applName>
            </default>
            <abc>
                <applName>appl1-abc-1</applName>
                <applName>appl2-abc-1</applName>
            </abc>
        </applList>
        <applList name='2'>
            <default>
                <applName>appl1-default-2</applName>
                <applName>appl2-default-2</applName>
            </default>
            <abc>
                <applName>appl1-abc-2</applName>
                <applName>appl2-abc-2</applName>
            </abc>
        </applList>
    </applLists>
</config>");

var applNames =
    from applList in config.Elements("applLists").Elements("applList")
    from al in applList.Elements()
    where (string)applList.Attribute("name") == name
    where al.Name == company
    select al.Value;

if (!applNames.Any()) {
    applNames =
        from applList in config.Elements("applLists").Elements("applList")
        from al in applList.Elements()
        where (string)applList.Attribute("name") == name
        where al.Name == "default"
        select al.Value;
}

return applNames.ToList<string>();
```

Two questions:

1. The problem is that the result is not a list of two values. Instead I get a string back which is "appl1-abc-1appl2-abc-1". What am I doing wrong?? Please help!!
2. Is there a possibility to combine both LINQ queries into one? Mean if the company "abc" is not found the applNames of the "default" node is returned.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are selecting 'al' which isn't part of the query.  What is 'al'?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [LinqPad program](https://www.linqpad.net/) using method syntax:

```
void Main()
{
    SoQuestion("1", "abc").Dump();
    SoQuestion("1", "foo").Dump();
    SoQuestion("2", "abc").Dump();
    SoQuestion("2", "bar").Dump();
}

public List<string> SoQuestion(string name, string company)
{
    XElement config = GetXml();

    var applList = config.Elements("applLists")
                         .Elements("applList")
                         .Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == name);
    return applList.Elements(company).Any()
         ? applList.Elements(company)
                   .Elements("applName")
                   .Select(x => x.Value).ToList()
         : applList.Elements("default")
                   .Elements("applName")
                   .Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
}

private XElement GetXml()
{
    return XElement.Parse(
    @"<config>
        <applLists>
            <applList name='1'>
                <default>
                    <applName>appl1-default-1</applName>
                    <applName>appl2-default-1</applName>
                </default>
                <abc>
                    <applName>appl1-abc-1</applName>
                    <applName>appl2-abc-1</applName>
                </abc>
            </applList>
            <applList name='2'>
                <default>
                    <applName>appl1-default-2</applName>
                    <applName>appl2-default-2</applName>
                </default>
                <abc>
                    <applName>appl1-abc-2</applName>
                    <applName>appl2-abc-2</applName>
                </abc>
            </applList>
        </applLists>
    </config>");
}
```

This gives the following result:

[image]

I haven't worked with XML in a while, so there may be better properties or method calls to use.

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback! Works great. Saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the `a` variable in the `from a in applList.Elements()` part of the query is actually supposed to be `al`, otherwise the code doesn't compile.  With that change, I can reproduce your problem.

The reason you are getting your result as concatenated strings is because you are asking for `al.Value` which refers to the value of the `<abc>` node.  [`XElement.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the concatenated text of all child elements.  What you really want is the values of the `<applName>` children of `<abc>`.  So you need to modify your query to get those instead:

```
var applNames =
    from applList in config.Elements("applLists").Elements("applList")
    from al in applList.Elements()
    from an in al.Elements()
    where (string)applList.Attribute("name") == name
    where al.Name == company
    select an.Value;
```

To combine the two queries together into one, I would rewrite it like this:

```
var applNames = config.Elements("applLists").Elements("applList")
    .Where(al => al.Attribute("name").Value == name)
    .Select(al => al.Elements(company).Any() ? al.Elements(company) : al.Elements("default"))
    .SelectMany(e => e.Elements("applName"))
    .Select(an => an.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ihbRC6

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback! Works great. Saved my day.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Don't forget to [mark an answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel your question has been answered adequately.